# Frequent job switches before migration to another country

Tags: job-change, software-development, relationships, career-switch, relocation

Context:

I am working as a software support engineer/team leader in a non-IT company doing desktop applications. The domain I am working is geography specific i.e. the jobs are in Europe and some parts of Asia only. My role involves debugging and developing small/medium features of a large complex codebase. Most part of my job is bug-hunting and fixing.

For personal reasons, I am planning to migrate to Australia permanently with my family. But my exact job is not there. I have to switch domain but I can keep the language skills. Keeping this in my mind, I have been preparing myself for the past 2 years doing part-time courses and side projects. I am planning to job-hop a bit(carefully picking contract roles)  to prepare for my migration to be smooth.

Questions:

Is this kind of short-term jobs with a reason due to migration is reasonable on CV?

Am I thinking too-much and I can just stay at my current routine job and learn on the side? The learning out of day job is only helpful to some extent.

Comment: For the second question you're asking - what is the difference between job-hopping and keeping your day job and learning on the side when you thing about achieving your goals?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking that in case you take several short-term jobs when you migrate to a new country, will it look bad on your cv ?

Comment: @Juliana. Yes. Thinking 4 day work week with learning and doing freelancing

Comment: @anxious. You got it mate. Asking that exactly.

Comment: @T-Rex then I think specifying the country you're migrating to might bring some perspective from people working there. The market and what companies might be expecting of applicants might also be different.

Comment: @anxiousPI. Moving to Australia. Sydney or Melbourne.

Comment: @T-Rex What difference does it actually make for you with regards to achieving your goal? Which one would help you get there faster?

Answer (score 3):

Job hopping won't be an issue if your CV is clear about which roles were permanent versus contract.  There is far less expectation of longevity for contractors.  You may wish to guard against any perception that you kept getting fired from contracts by explicitly stating "Short term contracts" on that section of your CV.

By highlighting that you have been a contractor, you may then introduce concerns around salary.  Contracting generally pays significantly better than permanent employment so prospective employers may be concerned that you'll expect to retain an unusually high salary.  You could counter this by stating that you are actively seeking a permanent role in your cover letter and any introductory paragraph in your CV.

All that said, I think you'd find a job in your new country without all this hassle.  Your current job demonstrates skills in a programming language, supervisory experience, the ability to understand a complex problem domain and a willingness to get stuck into less glamorous tasks (bug fixing) when required.  It's very likely this will be enough to get you interviews.